# Specific battery percent is cut off for some unknown reason

Tags: display

I've tried to go into settings, but I dont see anything thing that can fix this issue.
Ex: instead of displaying 100%, it will say 10...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ALex.png)

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: Please put details of your Ubuntu version and hardware. Thank you.